# Angular 2 CLI / Typescript default JavaScript objects not available

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I installed the @anuglar/cli RC 0 and therefore updated to Node.js 6.10.0 and npm.js 4.3.0.

When I try to access default JS object like window or gobals like localStorage there are all undefined / not found by intellisense.

In older projects they are still working and found in 
`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\typescript\node_modules\typescript\lib\lib.dom.d.ts"`.

I've tried it on two windows machines with same result.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

// EDIT

The same happens on VSCode on Mac (same project via git checkout).

Comment: That's normally a situation where I would just delete the node_modules dir and reinstall while also making sure my npm global modules are up to date etc.

Comment: I've set up a blank VM and installed everything there: Node, npm, angular-cli.
Made new project `ng new myproject`
Installation was fine. But same result as described above.

Comment: The project is building correctly and works properly. This seems to be only a problem with TypeScript. When I generate a JS file, all works fine. Do I have to install any typings for that? It was never the case till now.

Comment: Do you have "dom" listed in the compilerOptions/lib node of your tsconfig.json file?

Answer (score 0):

As JB Nizet mentioned in his post adding "dom" to compilerOptions / lib ist the solution like so:

```js
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2016",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot!